# Can I browse my SQLite database-file from within vs2012 instead of the cmd?

Tags: c, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

Working in vs2012, I have created a SQLite database-file using "c" and everything looks fine, i.e: I can create tables and insert, update, delete and select record(s) (whether by compiling the code or write commands in cmd .

However, looking inside the database every-time to list tables and see their records from the cmd (or compiling my code) is a very irritating way of checking things.

is there is an alternative or an efficient way of doing this from within vs2012 itself something like a"view database structure from file" ? if not then in case there is another alternative please help me with it ? .. thanks in advance

I am new to database stuff and vs2012 IDE ..

---

**UPDATE**

I have found something called "SQLite Administrator", and it looks really helpful .. any new methods are more than welcome, specially from within vs2012 ...

Comment: maybe try googling "sqlite gui" or something?

Comment: Best guess: install the [ADO.NET provider](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) if you haven't already, and then Server Explorer (usually docked on the left-hand side), Data Connections, right-click add connection, Data Provider SQLite.

Comment: I tend to just put the database schema in a comment inside my code for quick lookups.

Comment: @r_ahlskog: I found a solution called "SQLite Administrator" and it looks very helpful ..

Comment: @Rup: Before, I've tried to install System.Data.Sqlite but it didn't work .. it failed the installation for a compatibility reason with my project.

Comment: @SergeyL.: As much as it sounds like a good practice to always put a token or a reminder, however it is not very efficient way to code while interacting with the DB ...

Comment: The best tool for administration of sqlite database I found so far is SQLite Maestro. However this is a commercial application.